# Is it possible to refresh the data after insert?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapping

I work with EF / AutoMapping. And I want after an Insert immediately the Id (PK) of the record.
How do you do that? Is it possible refreshing the data immediately after an insert?

```cs
public int InsertArtist(ArtistDto artistDto)
{
    Artist entity = _mapper.Map<ArtistDto, Artist>(artistDto);

    _artistRepository.Insert(entity);
    _artistRepository.Save();

    return entity.Id;
}
```

Comment: The entity tracked by the context will be updated automatically, are you not seeing that behavior?

Comment: Does `Id` have `DatabaseGenerated` attribute?

Comment: This solution works. But primary my code looked different. So I found the answer, without knowing it. Thank you for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

By default it is refreshing the data, suppose your Id is Database Generated, then after saving the entity, entity framework will assign and id to that entity and will return the referenced one.